# How to remove white color from the image?

Tags: html, css, image

The designer sent me an image for the footer(footer-logo.png). The image has an arc in the right side and the rest part is transparent. When I add the image to the html code, I get white pixels ? Why ?

[image: Here is the image to add]

And here is the white part:

[image]

Code used for the adding the image:

```
<div class="copyright footer-copyright">
<div class="footer copy-content">
<div class="container-fluid bg-3 text-center">
<div class="row">
<div id="footer-main-1" class="col-sm-2"><img class="footer-logo" alt="example" /></div>
<div id="footer-main-2" class="col-sm-7">
<div class="row">
<div id="footer-title" class="col-sm-12"><span><b>Online store</b></span></div>
<div id="footer-par-1" class="col-sm-6"><em class="fa fa-map-marker">&nbsp;</em>Headquarters: <span>Address Here</span></div>
<div id="footer-par-3" class="col-sm-3"><em class="fa fa-envelope">&nbsp;</em>Email: <a style="color: #ffffff;" href="mailto:support@example.com"><span>support@example.com</span></a></div>
<div id="footer-par-2" class="col-sm-3"><em class="fa fa-fax">&nbsp;</em>Toll free: <a style="color: #ffffff;" href="tel://000000000">000000000</a></div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="footer-main-3" class="col-sm-3">
<div class="footer-paylink" style="float: right; width: auto;">
<div class="footer_links"><a class="fisrt" href="{{store url=""}}">Home</a><a href="/about-us">About Us</a><a class="last" href="/contact">Contact Us</a></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

And here is the css for the image and for the background color:

```
.footer-logo{
    content:url("path-to-image/footer-logo.png");
    margin-right:20px;
}
.copyright{
    padding:0px 0px ;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(160,5,250,1) 1%, rgba(160,5,250,1) 6%, rgba(180,51,255,1) 24%, rgba(184,61,255,1) 47%, rgba(177,61,245,1) 68%, rgba(165,34,241,1) 79%, rgba(165,34,241,1) 100%) ;
}
```

How to remove the white pixels?

Comment: use photoshop ?

Comment: It is transparent in photoshop!

Comment: it has a bit of white border

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use photoshop the image has a small white border on the arc

***Original***

[image]

***Black background***

[image]

**Edit Image.**

Comment: Can I create an arc like in picture using html and css?